# Probability $a+b>c$ for $a,b,c$ uniform in $[0,1]$

Tags: probability

Let $a,b,c$ be drawn independently and uniformly at random from $[0,1]$. What is the probability that $a+b>c$?

We can represent $(a,b,c)$ as points in a unit cube, but as we want to consider the quantity $a+b$, it's not clear what to do.

Comment: Consider separately the cases $B<C$ and $B>C$.

Comment: @WillO For $b>c$ it's clear that $a+b>c$. For $b<c$ I don't see how to calculate the probability...

Comment: For $b<c$, you are integrating over the space where $c$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, $b$ ranges from $0$ to $c$, and $a$ ranges from $c-b$ to $1$.  Doing this in my head and combining it with the result for the case $b>c$, I get 5/6 for your probability, but there are about a thousand ways I could have made an error.  If you write it down, it  should be easy though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to go the geometric route, consider that you're looking for what portion of the unit cube is "below" the plane $a+b-c=0$. Now, what is that plane? Well, it contains $(0,0,0)$, and $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$ - it, in a way, cuts off the corner $(0,0,1)$. A cube is drawn below, with the intersection of the desired plane with the faces drawn as dashed lines:

[image]

Now, we are interested in the volume "below" the plane. The area above is a tetrahedron, with a right triangle base. The base has area $\frac{1}2$ and the tetrahedron has a height of $1$, so the area of the tetrahedron is $\frac{1}6$. Thus, as the area of the cube is $1$, the area below the plane is $1-\frac{1}6=\frac{5}6$, which is the desired probability.

Comment: An aside: Using the same method on hypercubes says that the probability of $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n-1} > a_n$ for variables chosen uniformly from $[0,1]$ is $1-\frac{1}{n!}$, as a corner is always cut off, accounting for $\frac{1}{n!}$ of the hyper-volume.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do this directly:  For us to have $c > a+b$ we must have 
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
0 \leq a < 1 \\
0 \leq b < 1-a \\
a+b < c \leq 1
\end{align}
\right.
$$
where the second condition is the key to the p[roblem:  If $a+b$ adds to more than $1$, you can't meet the condition for any $c$, so we have to carefully avoid counting that region.

The probability integral becomes
$$
\int_{a=0}^1
\int_{b=0}^{1-a}
\int_{c=a+b}^1 dc\, db \, da \\
=\int_{a=0}^1
\int_{b=0}^{1-a}
(1-a-b) \,db \, da \\
=\int_{a=0}^1
 \left( (1-a) - a(1-a) -\frac{1}{2}(1-a)^2 \right)\, da \\
=\frac{1}{2} \int_{a=0}^1 (1-a)^2 \, da = \frac{1}{2} \int_{x=1}^0 x^2 \, (-1)dx
=\frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: A sound answer, but it's for the complement of the condition in the original question.